# How can i enable cache on qt webkit

Tags: qtwebkit

I'm using webkit on qt platform, and I need to enable the cache function to use html5 apps that uses cache.manifest.
But, I'm using the OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled method, but this is not enough, its not working. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the path using [QWebSettings::setOfflineWebApplicationCachePath](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebsettings.html#setOfflineWebApplicationCachePath) (make sure the path exists, if necessary use some sensible subdirectory from [QDesktopServices::storageLocation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation)) and also the cache maximum size via [QWebSettings::setOfflineWebApplicationCacheQuota](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebsettings.html#setOfflineWebApplicationCacheQuota).